Is this a valid solution to the Diophantine equation?
I was recently searching for some Diophantine equations to practice at solving them and I stumbled across this problem:
Find all $n, k \in \Bbb N_0 $$\quad$  s.t.$\quad$ $2^{n-1}n+1=k^2$.
After I solved this problem i viewed the solution and it was quite defferent from mine. So I was wondering if my approach is correct and is there any flaws or easier solutions that I missed. Any help would be appreciated.
First of all I subtracted 1 from both sides to get $2^{n-1}n=(k-1)(k+1)$, since k is clearly odd $\gcd((k-1), (k+1))=2$, I divided both sides by 4 so that on the right hand side of the equation we have a product of two coprime numbers.$$2^{n-3}n=\frac{(k-1)}{2}\frac{(k+1)}{2}$$Since $\gcd(\frac{(k-1)}{2},\frac{(k+1)}{2})=1$, all power of 2 will be in the factorization of only one of those numbers. So we have two distinct cases to check:
$$ (1)\quad \frac{(k+1)}{2^{n-2}}\in\Bbb N$$$$(2)\quad \frac{(k-1)}{2^{n-2}}\in\Bbb N$$For n$\le3$ we have a single solution $(n,k)=(0,1)$, so assume that $n\ge4$:
Let $n=pq,\quad p,q\in\Bbb N,\quad \gcd(p,q)=1$. Now we can start checking case by case.
$\mathbf {(1)Case}$$\quad$\begin{cases}
\frac{(k+1)}{2}=2^{pq-3}p\\
\frac{(k-1)}{2}=q
\end{cases}
$$\begin{cases}
(k+1)=2^{pq-2}p\\
(k-1)=2q
\end{cases}$$
After subtracting one equation from another to cancel out $k$ and dividing both sides by 2 we get the following: $$2^{pq-3}p=q+1$$Because $2^{pq-3}|(q+1)$, $\quad(q+1)\ge 2^{pq-3}\ge 2^{q-3}, \quad (q+1)\ge 2^{q-3}$ which is only true for $q\le 5$. Also since $n=pq\ge 4$
$(q+1)=2^{pq-3}p\gt p\quad$ but because $p,q\in\Bbb N, q\ge p$. $$p\le q\le 5\Rightarrow pq=n\le 25$$
After checking all possible values of $n$ we get another solution, namely $(n, k)=(5, 9)$.
$\mathbf {(2)Case}$$\quad$\begin{cases}
\frac{(k+1)}{2}=q\\
\frac{(k-1)}{2}=2^{pq-3}p
\end{cases} After performing the same manipulations we end up with the following equation:$$q=1+2^{pq-3}p$$ $$1+2^{pq-3}p\gt 2^{pq-3}\ge 2^{q-3}$$ $$q\gt 2^{q-3}$$ Which is again, only true for $q\le 5$ or rather for $q\lt 6$.Also:
$$q=1+2^{pq-3}p\gt 1+p\gt p$$ $$p\lt q\lt 6$$ $$pq\lt36\Rightarrow pq \le 35$$We can again check all the values of $n$ from the set {$26; 27;\dots; 35$}, but we won't find any further solutions. So we can conclude that the only solutions are $(n, k)=(0, 1); (5, 9)$.

Not following.  First of all, in number theory, $p,q$ typically denote primes, not general natural numbers.  But here, you just mean general natural numbers, right?  No obvious reason $n$ should be a semiprime.  But, if $p,q$ are general natural numbers, then $p\times q$ can factor in all sorts of ways, depending on the factoring of $p,q$.

I think your argument works if you rephrase it.  Since we know that exactly one of the two right hand factors is odd, we know that we can write the right hand as $a\times (2^{n-3})b$  where $a,b\in \mathbb N$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$.  Of course, we don't know which of the original factors is which, and that gets us the two cases.

Yeah, I agree it was not the best choice of letters. Here I meant that p and q are positive integers, such that n=pq and gcd(p, q)=1. I forgot to write it out, but here p and q are basically defind to be either (k+1)/2^(n-2) or (k-1)/2^(n-2) or (k+1)/2 or (k-1)/2.

As I say, I think it's clearer if you simply split into cases directly, according to which factor is even.  If $\frac {k-1}2$ is even, write it as $2^{n-3}b$, and so on.  The cases then define your factors.

Oh, i see now. Yes it does seem more simple.

FYI, I found the duplicate using an Approach0 search. There are other duplicates too, e.g., Find all positive integers $n$ such that $,2^{n-1}\cdot n+1,$ is a perfect square.. Also, there's the AoPS threads Theory number problem & Georgian Team Selection Test 2005/7.
